# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown menu does not work, unsure of what is going on

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

my entire code is below, I do not have a main.js file yet. Just trying to get the dropdown menu to work but regardless of what I press the dropdown menu will not drop.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have console errors about loading `/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js`?

Comment: @JunlongWang Nope there was no error encounted for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Import Bootstrap using CDNs
and `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` should be present in Button which opens dropdown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
</head>
<body>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didnt need to use the cdn but i had to use data-bs-toggle, so i think the javascript was loaded properly but the toggle was not loaded properly. Regardless, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to link ##bootstrap. min. js## file in your script src.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).